# What is a good application to catalog CDs?

Tags: music, collection-manager

I have a music collection of 11,000+ CDs stored on shelves in order by artist.

I recently purchased a handy barcode scanner (for various reasons) and I would like to scan the UPC of these CDs and put them in a catalog. It would also be nice if the software could obtain the track and artist information and the cover art from a public database of these details.

What would be a good software application to use?

I'm looking just to catalog the CD metadata, not the actual music MP4 files. There are a number of applications that are "taggers", but these will not suit my needs as I do not intend to "digitize" this collection.

Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 2):

### [Collectorz.com Music Collector](http://www.collectorz.com/music/)

- Has Mac and PC version
- Standard: €24.95; Pro: €39.95
- [Trial version](http://www.collectorz.com/music/freetrial.php)

  > > The free trial edition is limited to 100 albums and a maximum of 200 searches in our online album database.
  > >     Of course the licensed version has no limits at all.
  >
  > Interesting:
  >
  > > Submit your email address below and instantly receive:
  > >
  > > - The download link for your free trial edition.
  > > - **Your personal €4.00 discount coupon.**
- Collectorz.com not only has a Music Collector, but also a [Movie Collector](http://www.collectorz.com/movie/), a [Book Collector](http://www.collectorz.com/book/), a [Comic Collector](http://www.collectorz.com/comic/), and a [Game Collector.](http://www.collectorz.com/game/)
- Supports barcode scanner
- Has its own online database with millions of CDs, looks at other databases if CD isn't in its own one
- Supports Windows 8 (and some earlier versions too)
- [More features](http://www.collectorz.com/music/features.php) (warning: veeeery long page - mostly because it's cluttered with screenshots)
- Difference between both versions:
  [image: Difference between both versions]
- [Last update on 16th of April 2014](http://www.collectorz.com/music/updates-win.php)
- ['Review' on black-sabbath.com](http://www.black-sabbath.com/2012/01/collectorz-music-catalogue-software/) and [on popbunker.net (a... bit... outdated - 2010)](http://www.popbunker.net/2010/04/review-collectorzcom-collection-database-software/)

Comment: btw, I have no association whatsoever with any of the software mentioned.

Comment: Very helpful comments. I had looked at the Collectorz app and found the user interface to be somewhat dated and cumbersome. The other two are worthy candidates.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I am testing Readerware (http://www.readerware.com). I have used my scanner to digitize about 100 CDs from my collection. The software searches Amazon.com and a number of other international sources to get CD information and tracks, but it takes a good minute to process the results for about 25 discs. Not a bad application if used sporadically, but it would be nice to have something stronger and faster. Also, i haven't been able to scan a barcode from the old BMG music service and get it locate the disc.

Comment: I'm happy to hear you've also done some research yourself (I could've mentioned more software, but then the list would've been quite big). You'll probably find problems - minor or major - in every product you use... Well, I don't believe in 'perfect software' myself anyway (even paid). Good luck with trying out the software!

Comment: Can you please split this up into one answer per program? As it stands votes on your combined answer do not assist anyone in seeing which of your suggested programs is better than any of the others.

Comment: Done. Used collectorz.com as first part.

Comment: I would be a little careful of Collectorz. My version decided that every Frank Sinatra track was an album in itself and decided that I have 125 Sinatra albums. When I queried this with Collectorz they had no idea what to do. When this started to happen to other artists I gave up.

Comment: FYI, the last time I contacted Music Collector / Collectorz to explain a name of a category, I basically was told that if I didn't know what a term meant, I didn't need to know. I've used the program for over a year but with this last responce from them, I'm looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

### [OrangeCD Catalog](http://www.firetongue.com/cd-database.html)

- [Costs $34.95](http://www.firetongue.com/purchase.html) [(around €25.30 atm](http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=USD&to=EUR&amount=34.95)) 'per computer'
- Has a fully-functional 30-day trial
- 90-day money back guarantee and free life-time upgrades. They even offer a CD with the software! Wow...
- Supports barcode scanner (CueCat barcode recommended, website says - whatever)
- You can "search web sites like eBay, Amazon, or Google for album price or information"
- You can track who borrows your CD's (might be handy with so many CD's)
- Supports [Racks & Tags](http://www.racksandtags.com/)
- You can add all kinds of (custom) information for tracks, albums and artists
- More features on [13](http://www.firetongue.com/cd-database.html)
- [Screenshots](http://www.firetongue.com/screens.html)
- Supports Windows up to and including Vista. *"OK, guys, I'll just pretend you said it supports 7 and 8 too"*
- [Latest update on 27th of February of... *drumroll* This year!](http://www.firetongue.com) Impressive, but not as impressive as Collectorz Music Collector
- Dutch review on PCM here: [OrangeCD Catalog 6 | PCM](http://www.pcmweb.nl/review/orangecd-catalog-6.html)

Answer (score 0):

### [CD Storage Master](http://www.cdstorager.com)

- Firstly: it's paid software. Standard Version: $29.95 ([€21.68](http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=USD&to=EUR&amount=29.95)); Professional Version: $59.95 ([€43.40](http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=USD&to=EUR&amount=59.95))
- (yes, it has a free trial, with limits)
- Don't see anything about a CD limit (except for the [trial version](http://www.cdstorager.com/download.htm), but that's to be expected)
- It supports barcode scanners
- It supports real CD's, but also all kinds of music files. And it can also be used to catalog movies, "data" and games
- Supports Amazon and CDDB
- More features, and differences between different versions here: "[Features - A powerful CD (...)](http://www.cdstorager.com/features.htm)"
- It does have one catch: the last version was released on the 29th of April **2011**. But this probably isn't such a big problem.
  [image: Windows XP, 2000, ME, 98, NT, Vista, 7]
  (and probably also Windows 8)
- Couldn't find any reviews for it

So, a lot to explore, 'ey?
(*[I found this comparison of software from 2009 that might help you a bit](http://www.afterdawn.com/news/article.cfm/2009/08/03/catalog_your_music_4_programs_compared)*)